# R: na in ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I have created the variable np_collpar with the following code

```
a <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,1,1)
c1 <- c(9,3,NA,NA,NA,5)
c2 <- c(5,NA,NA,NA,5,2)
c3 <- c(3,7,NA,NA,NA,9)

df <- data.frame(a,c1,c2,c3)
np_collpar <- ifelse(a==1 & (!is.na(c1) | !is.na(c2) | !is.na(c3)),1,0)
```

I want np_collpar to be 1 for rows 5 and 6 and 0 for rows 1-4. However, NA is returned for rows 1 and 2.  The Boolean reasoning behing the ifelse statement should be correct. Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what happens if `a` is `NA`. Add `(!is.na(a))` like below.

```
> np_collpar <- ifelse(a==1 & (!is.na(a)) & (!is.na(c1) | !is.na(c2) | !is.na(c3)),1,0)
> np_collpar
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Other option using `complete.cases()`, which returns `FALSE` if the vector has an `NA`, and `TRUE` otherwise.

```
np_collpar <- ifelse(a==1 & (complete.cases(a)) & (complete.cases(c1) | complete.cases(c2) | complete.cases(c3)), 1, 0)
np_collpar

[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1
```